# Add items to listview after cleared

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am adding all the textboxes and labels to display in the listview. When I click the clear button everything on my form clears as it should, but when I then want to add more items to the listview, nothing displays in the listview, and my header information is also cleared. Can someone please assist?

```
Public Class Form2

    Dim decTotalDue As Decimal
    Dim intTotalItems As Integer

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtUnitPrice.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddItem.Click

        Dim decUnitPrice As Decimal
        Dim intQuantity As Integer
        Dim decTotal As Decimal
        Dim decTotalPayable As Decimal
        Dim item As New ListViewItem

        Decimal.TryParse(txtUnitPrice.Text, decUnitPrice)
        Integer.TryParse(txtQuantity.Text, intQuantity)

        decTotal = decUnitPrice * intQuantity
        lblTotal.Text = decTotal.ToString("C2")

        decTotalDue = decTotal + decTotalDue
        lblTotalDue.Text = decTotalDue.ToString("C2")

        intTotalItems = intQuantity + intTotalItems
        lblTotalItems.Text = intTotalItems.ToString

        decTotalPayable = decTotalDue
        lblTotalPayable.Text = decTotalPayable.ToString("C2")

        lblTotalPayable.Hide()
        lblTotalItems.Hide()

        item = ListView1.Items.Add(cboItemName.Text)
        item.SubItems.Add(txtUnitPrice.Text)
        item.SubItems.Add(txtQuantity.Text)
        item.SubItems.Add(lblTotal.Text)
        ListView1.ForeColor = Color.White

        txtUnitPrice.Text = decUnitPrice.ToString("C2")

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPurchase_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPurchase.Click

        lblTotalItems.Show()
        lblTotalPayable.Show()

        cboItemName.Text = String.Empty
        txtUnitPrice.Clear()
        txtQuantity.Clear()
        lblTotal.Text = ""
        lblTotalDue.Text = ""

        ListView1.Clear()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculateChange_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculateChange.Click

        Dim decCashTenderted As Decimal
        Dim decChange As Decimal

        Decimal.TryParse(txtCashTendered.Text, decCashTenderted)

        txtCashTendered.Text = decCashTenderted.ToString("C2")

        decChange = decCashTenderted - decTotalDue
        lblChange.Text = decChange.ToString("C2")

        If decCashTenderted < decTotalDue Then
            MessageBox.Show("Cash Tendered is less than Total Due", "Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

        cboItemName.Text = String.Empty
        txtCashTendered.Clear()
        txtUnitPrice.Clear()
        txtQuantity.Clear()
        lblTotalDue.Text = ""
        lblTotalItems.Text = ""
        lblTotalPayable.Text = ""
        lblChange.Text = ""
        ListView1.Clear()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

MSDN on the behaviour of the [Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) function is:

> You can use this method to remove all items and columns from the ListView control without having to call the individual Clear methods from the ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection and ListView.ListViewItemCollection classes.

From what you describe you want, you should be doing is calling:

```
ListView1.Items.Clear()
```

This will remove just the items that are displayed and not remove the column definitions.